# How to convert zip file containing xml into byte array without not using zipfile entries in java

Tags: web-services, arrays, file-transfer, zip

I have a zip file containing xml file generated in Java.And I will send the zip file to Web Service in byte array format.The code snippet to convert zip file into byte array is

```
public static byte[] FileToArrayOfBytes(ZipFile file) throws IOException {

         final Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = file.entries();
         final ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

         BufferedInputStream istream = new BufferedInputStream(
                       file.getInputStream(entry));
         int file_size       = (int) entry.getCompressedSize();
         byte[] blob = new byte[file_size];
         int bytes_read      = 0;
         int offset          = 0;

         while ((bytes_read = istream.read(blob, 0, file_size)) != -1) {
                offset += bytes_read;
         }

         file.close();
         istream.close();

         return blob;
   }
```

When I send the byte array returned from above method,web service is returning an error message as 'invalid file extensions'.Normally we know web service accepts zip file.

Can you help me how can I handle the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled the my problem as following

```
public static byte[] convertFileIntoArrayOfBytes(String zipFilePath) {

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    File file = new File(zipFilePath);

    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

    try {
        // convert file into array of bytes
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);
        fileInputStream.read(bFile);
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bFile;
}
```